# Why can't I acces a static function in a static Object from the same Class?

Tags: javascript, function, static

i'm learning extends Class in javascript with narrow function class.

In the Cards Class:
I've made an static Object and i can't have acces to the static variable this.number from the Object info, precisely in "function".

Can you give me a way to have access to static variable. I can't change the structure of the Object

Zoom on the problem:

```
  static number = 44;

  static info = {
    name : "Games",
    function(game){
      console.log("fonction");
      console.log("best card is "+game.best);
      game.draw();
      console.log(this.number);  <======= CAN'T HAVE ACCES TO STATIC VARIABLE NUMBER 
    }
  }
```

I call with :

> President.info.function(partie1);

It return :

```
best card is 2 Heart
7 Heart
undefined
```

I've an another question why "partie1.name()" give me the error
"TypeError: partie1.name is not a function"
The whole code

```
class Games {
  constructor(name)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.joueurs = 2;
  }

  name(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  nombre(){
    console.log(this.joueurs);
  }
}

let Cards = Base => class extends Base {
  constructor(name){
    super(name);
    this.best = "King Heart";
  }

  static number = 44;

  draw(){
    console.log("7 Heart");
  }

  static info = {
    name : "Games",
    function(game){
      console.log("fonction");
      console.log("best card is "+game.best);
      game.draw();
      console.log(this.number);
    }
  }
}

let Dices = Base => class extends Base {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.Dices = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  }
}


class President extends Cards(Games){
  constructor(){
    super("President");
    this.best = "2 Heart";
  }
  
  static drawBest(game){
    console.log(game.best);
  }

}


let duel = new Games("duel");
duel.nombre(); // 2

let partie1 = new President();
President.drawBest(partie1); 
//2 Heart

//partie1.name(); 
//TypeError: partie1.name is not a function 

President.info.function(partie1); 
// function 
// best card is 2 Heart
// 7 Heart
// undefined ???
```

Comment: I'm very confused.  Why are you returning class definitions from arrow functions?

Comment: because thanks to that i can extend my class game. 
Game is the Base of every class and i can extend it with Cards or Dice if i want to create an card game or an dice game

Comment: `this` is your `info` object that you called the `.function` method on. Don't nest objects if that's not what you want. An alternative could be using an arrow function, but really it's unclear what the `info` method should be doing, why it is taking an instance as an argument, and why it isn't just a simple instance method instead.

Comment: I can't change the structure because the object info will be a common object on all my class just with different value and I call this info object in an another file.
Now i understand why it isn't working but how can i have access to the static value ? Maybe an export ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED :

```
static info = {
    name : "Games",
    function : (game) => {
      console.log("fonction");
      console.log("best card is "+game.best);
      game.draw();
      console.log(Cards.number); //undefined
      console.log(this.number); //undefined
    }
  }
```